# PHP Support Form - Undefined Index

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm having issues geting my form to submit correctly. I have successfully used code almost exactly like this one, but i can't seem to find the issue. It keeps saying 'undefined index' on every index that comes from my form's page except `$subject=$_POST['subject'];`. I have included both my form and php script, can anyone see the issue?

```
<form name="support" id="support" method="post" action="process.php">
    <input type="text" value="Name" name="name" id="name" /> <br/>
    <select name="subject" name="subject" id="subject">
        <option value="Suggestion">Suggestion</option>
        <option value="Website Error">Website Error</option>
        <option value="Forums">Forums</option> 
        <option value="Error 404">Error 404</option> 
        <option value="Other">Other</option> 
    </select> <br/> 
    <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="content" id="Content">Please type your message here!</textarea> <br/> 
    <input type hidden value="<br/>" name="br" id="br" /> 
    <input type hidden value="<p>" name="sp" id="sp" /> 
    <input type hidden value="</p>" name="ep" id="ep" /> 
    <input type hidden value='<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/layout.css">' name="css" id="css" /> 
    <input type hidden value="<h1>Support Ticket" name="head" id="head" /> 
    <input type hidden value='<script src="/scripts/copyright.js"></script>' name="copy" id="copy" /> 
    <input type hidden value="Status: Not View" name="stat" id="stat"/> 
    <input type="submit" name="s1" id="s1" value="Submit"> 
</form>

<? 
$name=$_POST['name']; 
$subject=$_POST['subject']; 
$con=$_POST['content']; 
$br=$_POST['br']; 
$sp=$_POST['sp']; 
$ep=$_POST['ep']; 
$css=$_POST['css']; 
$head=$_POST['head']; 
$copy=$_POST['copy']; 
$stat=$_POST['stat']; 
$stamp=date("jS \of F Y h:i:s A"); 
$ran=rand(1000000,9999999); 
$fp=fopen("tickets/$ran.html","a");
$savestring=$css.$head.$sp.$name." - ".$subject." - ".$con." - Ticket# ".$ran.$br.$stat.$br."Submitted: ".$stamp.$ep.$copy; 
fwrite($fp,$savestring); 
fclose($fp); 
echo"<p>Thank you $name!</p>"; 
echo "<p>Your Ticket Number# $ran</p>"; 
echo "<p>Submitted: $stamp</p>" 
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, but please format your code properly (start with indentation e.g.) - this is a mess.

Comment: Yeah, I need to get better at that

Comment: You have `name="subject" name="subject"` written twice, remove one. Also make sure short tags are set to "ON".

Comment: `<input type hidden value="<br/>" name="br" id="br" />` — what on earth is this?? If you must include `<` and `>`, use `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: There on, and although I did miss that mistake (thankyou btw) that's ironically the only only on not getting an 'undefined index' notice

Comment: This I why my code is sloppy. I don't have internet on my computer right now. I'm running wamp server locally on my WiFi. I made a txt file containing my code, accessed it with my phone nd copied nd pasted it here. My html looks incorrect, but the spaces are where the correct symbols should be. That being said, can anyone see my issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a mess - if your format it properly, you notice maybe, your html code has errors

i.e.

```
<input type hidden value="</p>" name="ep" id="ep"/>
```

i think, you mean something like

```
<input type="hidden" value="&lt;/p&gt;" name="ep" id="ep"/>
```

also you should use `<?php` instead of `<?`, because the short syntax is disabled on *many* servers.

Btw. your code works in current version if chrome - so I think, its because your html syntax. If you clean your mess up, it should work on every browser

Comment: "_also you should use <?php instead of <?, because the short syntax is disabled on most servers._" - **completely rubbish**, and even so - it obviously works for the OP. But +1 anyway for pointing out `<` -> `&lt;`

Comment: That was a copy nd paste issue, my html doesn't say that. Sorry, I'm on a cheep phone

Comment: @davidkonrad why? The current default value for `short_open_tag` is 1, but i times of earlier versions(i.e. 5.3) this wasn't the case.. ok, I shouldn't say on most servers, but on many

Comment: "_The current default value for short_open_tag is 1_", yeah, meaning it is allowed. I havent seen any server yet, that didnt accepted `<? ?>`, and I have seen a lot of PHP-servers over the past 10 years, and installed a lot of servers myself.

Comment: As said, Im not the only one facing this problem with earlier versions.. try to google `php 5.3 short tags`

Comment: I figured it out, I needed to enable 'zlib output compression'